# ExoPlayer2 Updated Way to implement setControlDispatcher

Tags: android, dependencies, exoplayer

I'm currently working on updating an android app for an open source project, at the moment I'm bringing a ton of the dependencies up to date, and this includes Exoplayer. One of the changes I'm hitting a road block on is the following snippets of code:

```
StyledPlayerView playerView = root.findViewById(R.id.file_view_exoplayer_view);
View playbackSpeedContainer = playerView.findViewById(R.id.player_playback_speed);
TextView textPlaybackSpeed = playerView.findViewById(R.id.player_playback_speed_label);
textPlaybackSpeed.setText(DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_SPEED);


playerView.setControlDispatcher(new DefaultControlDispatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(Player player, boolean playWhenReady) {
        isPlaying = playWhenReady;
        return super.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player, playWhenReady);
    }
});
```

So the `setControlDispatcher`has been deprecated (not much in ways of documentation), I had to look at the commit history on the ExoPlayer github to find when it was removed. But it was mentioned to use `ForwardingPlayer` or something else (I can't remember or find it again) instead. So I was wondering if someone knows of a good way to re-implement the above with the updated methods!

Comment: the same here please

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me! Surprised I haven't seen any input yet honestly, even a pointer to some reference!

Comment: I am still working here so When I found solution I will give u feedback